# How to write a function to rearrange a list according to the dictionary of index

Tags: python

How to write a function to rearrange a list according to the dictionary of index in python?

for example,

```
    L=[('b',3),('a',2),('c',1)]

    dict_index={'a':0,'b':1,'c':2}
```

I want a list of :

```
   [2,3,1]
```

where 2 is from 'a',3 is from 'b' and 1 is from 'c', but rearrange only the number in L according to the dict_index

Answer (score 1):

Try this (edited with simpler solution):

```
L=[('b',3),('a',2),('c',1)]

dict_index={'a':0,'b':1,'c':2}

# Creates a new empty list with a "slot" for each letter.
result_list = [0] * len(dict_index)

for letter, value in L:
    # Assigns the value on the correct slot based on the letter.
    result_list[dict_index[letter]] = value

print result_list # prints [2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: you don't need the result_list = [0] * len(dict_index) you can just do:
result_list = []
and then:
result_list[index] = dict_value[letter]

Comment: Doesn't work here: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` . Try `[][2] = 'some value'`

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` and the `.sort()` method of lists take a `key` parameter:

```
>>> L=[('b',3),('a',2),('c',1)]
>>> dict_index={'a':0,'b':1,'c':2}
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x: dict_index[x[0]])
[('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1)]
```

and so

```
>>> [x[1] for x in sorted(L, key=lambda x: dict_index[x[0]])]
[2, 3, 1]
```

should do it.  For a more interesting example -- yours happens to match alphabetical order with the numerical order, so it's hard to see that it's really working -- we can shuffle `dict_index` a bit:

```
>>> dict_index={'a':0,'b':2,'c':1}
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x: dict_index[x[0]])
[('a', 2), ('c', 1), ('b', 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehensions:

```
def index_sort(L, dict_index):
    res = [(dict_index[i], j) for (i, j) in L]     #Substitute in the index
    res = sorted(res, key=lambda entry: entry[0])  #Sort by index
    res = [j for (i, j) in res]                    #Just take the value

    return res
```